# Why the output is not showing up in the last step of loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I wrote a code which loops through number 1 to 20. If number is divisible by 3, it prints 'Julia'. If number is divisible by 5, it prints 'James'. And if number is divisible by 15, it prints 'Julia-James'. But in last number 20, the output is the number not 'James'.

```
var x = 1;
while (x < 20) {
    x % 15 === 0 ? console.log('Julia-James') : x % 5 === 0 ? console.log('James') : x % 3 === 0 ? console.log('Julia') : console.log(x);
    x++;
}
console.log(x);
```

I expect the output of 20 to be 'James'. But actual output is the number itself.

Comment: At the End x = 19 then you will get 19 itself,  You need to use x <= 20(correct condition).

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

It will break the loop when x = 20, therefore it will not execute for x = 20. Also it is giving 20 as out put is because of the last line `console.log(x);` Please find below the correct code.

```js
var x = 1;
while (x <= 20) {
  x % 15 === 0 ? console.log('Julia-James') : x % 5 === 0 ? console.log('James') : x % 3 === 0 ? console.log('Julia') : console.log(x);
  x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iterates over all the numbers that are strictly smaller than 20. The last number you check is 19, which is neither divisible by `3` nor by `5`. You should fix the loop's condition to include `20`:

```
while (x <= 20) {
// Here --^
```

Answer (score 0):

At the End x = 19 then you will get 19 itself,  You need to use x <= 20(correct condition).

```
while(x<=20){
  // body
}
```